# Setting a cookie in a Django view

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie in a view using the following code.

```
def index(request):
    resp = HttpResponse("Setting a cookie")
    resp.set_cookie('name', 'value')
    if 'name' in request.COOKIES:
        print "SET"
    else:
        print "NOT SET"
    return render(request, 'myapp/base.html', {})
```

When the view is loaded, the console prints out `NOT SET`, which means the cookie was not set. In every tutorial/doc, this seems to be the method used. However, it simply does not work for me :/

Any help? I am using Django 1.9.8, and I am running the app in my local server, or `127.0.0.1:8000`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a response and setting a cookie on it, but then you don't actually do anything with that response. The `render` shortcut creates its own response which is the one actually sent back to the browser.

You should capture the return value from render, and set the cookie on that:

```
if 'name' in request.COOKIES:
    print "SET"
else:
    print "NOT SET"
resp = render(request, 'myapp/base.html', {})
resp.set_cookie('name', 'value')
return resp
```